# Improper integral $\int_0^{2020} \frac{\sqrt{x}\arctan{x^\frac{3}{2}}}{\ln(1+x^2)\sin(\sqrt{x})}dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

I have to investigate convergence of improper integral $$\int_0^{2020} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}\arctan{(x^\frac{3}{2}})}{\ln(1+x^2)\sin(\sqrt{x})}dx$$ Singularities are $k^2\pi^2$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Integral can be written as sum of integrals whose bounds are singularities. I got that the last integral in the sum diverges, therefore $\int_0^{2020} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}\arctan{(x^\frac{3}{2}})}{\ln(1+x^2)\sin(\sqrt{x})}dx$ diverges.
Am I right? Is this explanation satisfying?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $k>0$ such that $k^2\pi^2 < 2020$ we have that for $x \in \mathcal U(k^2\pi^2)$,
\begin{align}
\sin(\sqrt{x}) &= \sin(\sqrt{x-k^2\pi^2+k^2\pi^2}) \\
&= \sin\left(k\pi\sqrt{\frac{x}{k^2\pi^2}-1+1}\right) \\
&\sim \sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2} \left(\frac{x}{k^2\pi^2}-1\right)\right) \\
&=\sin\left(\frac{x-k^2\pi^2}{2k\pi}\right) \\
&\sim x-k^2\pi^2
\end{align}
So the integral diverges at every singular point $k^2\pi^2$.